# Boost python: Argument Error lvalue between Wrapped and Base class

Tags: python, c++, boost-python

In the Python code below, the `findFactory` returns a `FactoryBase` instead of a `FactoryBaseWrapper`.
And I think this may be the cause of the problem.
Do you know how to tell python that FactoryBaseWrapper inherit from FactoryBase?
I tried "bases" in the class_ like this:

```
class_<FactoryBaseWrapper, bases<FactoryBase> boost::noncopyable>( "FactoryBase", no_init )
```

But It doesn't compile. Seems like I need to make the interface from FactoryBase too. But I can't, I need FactoryBaseWrapper because of a pure virtual function in Factorybase.

Thanks

Python Code:

```
_sourceFactory = _myFactoryMgr.findFactory(name)
foo = _sourceFactory.getOrCreateBase(myObj) # Problem Here
```

BoostPython Module:

```
class_<FactoryMgr, boost::noncopyable>("FactoryMgr",no_init)
  .def("findFactory",&FactoryMgr::findFactory, return_value_policy<reference_existing_object>());

class_<FactoryBaseWrapper, boost::noncopyable>( "FactoryBase", no_init )
.def( "getOrCreateIndicator", &FactoryBaseWrapper::getOrCreateIndicator, return_value_policy<reference_existing_object>())
```

Cpp functions & Classes :

```
        class FactoryMgr
        {    
          FactoryBase* FactoryMgr::findFactory( const std::string& name );
        }
        class FactoryBaseWrapper :public FactoryBase, public wrapper<FactoryBase>
        {
           Base* FactoryBase::getOrCreateBase ( const CustomObject* myObj);
           Base* createBase( string str )
           {
             return this->get_override( "createBase" )();
           }
        } 
        class FactoryBase
        {
           virtual Base* createBase( string str )=0;
           ...
        }
```

I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "XXX", line 149, in YYYY
_sourceFactory.getOrCreateBase(myObj)
Boost.Python.ArgumentError: Python argument types in
    FactoryBase.getOrCreateBase(FactoryBase, CustomObject)
did not match C++ signature:
    getOrCreateBase(FactoryBaseWrapper {lvalue}, Interface::CustomObject const*)
```

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE].

Comment: What information do you need ? What's not clear?
I can't copy the code, I had to change everything.
If i give more detail, I'll have to just pust the whole thing.

Comment: Nothing is clear. This isn't a complete or verifiable example. I don't know what the types are in C++ or what their relationship is to each other. Also `no_init` means the class isn't initializable from Python, but you're initializing it from Python, so that's also not clear.

Comment: I'm not initializing anything in Python. Just getting pointers to c++ object already existing. There was a Typo for the FactoryMnr(). It's Corrected now.
FactoryBaseWrapper is a wrapper around FactoryBase. I thought that was obvious in boost::python. I'll put the minimum for The wrapper too.

Comment: Nothing is "obvious." If it was, you wouldn't have a problem. And it wasn't a typo either - you posted different code to that which is causing you problems. Please reread what constitutes a [mcve] and provide one. With such a thing, I have no idea what your code is right now so I can't very well help you.

Comment: Ok, let's someone else can . Thank you